# How to use sap.ui.unified.FileUploader with custom blob or blobURL?

Tags: sapui5

I'm doing client side image resizing prior to upload. The standard behavior of the FileUploader element will take the specified file and submit it as is. I have a blob with a resized version of the selected image ready to be uploaded. How can I set this blob in the FileUploader and make sure that it's not taking the original file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With modern browsers I would send `Blob` with JavaScript native [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data): (for browser compatibility check [`send(FormData)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Browser_compatibility))

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", sUploadUrl, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  // Uploaded.
};
var oFormData = new FormData();
oFormData.append("myFileUpload", blob);
oReq.send(formData);
```

It sends the same request as the FileUploader.

There's no method to set the file in the FileUploader component. 
The file input wrapped in the component can be accessed for files `fileUploader.oFileUpload.files` but it makes the inner state of the component inconsistent.